# How can I use router in store for Quasar

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, store, quasar

I'm trying to redirect to dashboard after login.
I found this in app.js file that

`// make router instance available in store store.$router = router`

So I codede that in my login method of auth.js file like below.

`store.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })`

But there is nothing to happen.

How can I use router in vuex store file?

Answer (score 1):

Router is not available in the store directly. You might have to use plugin which makes the router available to the store.

Here is the [Vuex-Router](https://github.com/geekytime/vuex-router) plugin which helps to access router to the store.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call `router.push` in an vuex action?

If so i am doing the same in my quasar v2 project

`store/auth/actions.js`

```
import { api } from 'boot/axios'

export function login({ dispatch, commit }, data) {
    return api.post('/user/login', data).then(res => {
        commit('setToken', res.data.token)

        this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })   // <-- What you are looking for?

    }).catch(err => {
        let msg = err.response.data || 'Error occurred'
        return Promise.reject(msg)
    })
}
```